# How to turn on/off developer options in Android from source code?

Tags: android

I want to create an app widget that will turn on/off developer options on click, but I didn´t found any command, that can handle it. Any suggestion ?

Comment: That should not be possible, except perhaps on rooted devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm glad that it's not possible. If I imagine that apps could actually access developer options programmatically, that would be nasty. But is it possible on rooted devices or not?

Comment: @CommonsWare And if it was rooted, how to enable/disable developer options? And enable or disable some of items in there?